How to add a form validation for flutter DropDownMenu (Not DropDown Button)
I am little lost on how to add form validation for the new avatar of DropDown in flutter i.e. DropDownMenu
In the official doc for DropdownButton I see

Updating to DropdownMenu There is a Material 3 version of this
component, DropdownMenu that is preferred for applications that are
configured for Material 3 (see ThemeData.useMaterial3). The
DropdownMenu widget's visuals are a little bit different, see the
Material 3 spec at m3.material.io/components/menus/guidelines for more
details.

But I dont see an equivalent for DropDownButtonFormField
Could someone please give me a pointer

validator is not currently supported by the out-of-the-box DropdownMenu - see official docs at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenu-class.html.
However, it seems support is in progress, and in the interim there is a workaround - see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/141941.
To use the workaround, copy the whole class DropdownMenuFormField<T> extends FormField<T> from https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/141941#issuecomment-2135735733 into your project, and in your code change references from DropdownMenu to DropdownMenuFormField, after which you can use the validator in the same way you can with DropdownButtonFormField.

  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

  void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
  }

 class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
     home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Dropdown Menu Form Validation'),
      ),
      body: DropdownForm(),
     ),
   );
 }
}

 class DropdownForm extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _DropdownFormState createState() => _DropdownFormState();
}

 class _DropdownFormState extends State<DropdownForm> {
 final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 String _selectedItem;

 List<String> _items = [
'Item 1',
'Item 2',
'Item 3'];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Form(
   key: _formKey,
   child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    children: <Widget>[
      DropdownButtonFormField(
        value: _selectedItem,
        items: _items.map((item) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: item,
            child: Text(item),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _selectedItem = value;
          });
        },
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null) {
            return 'Please select an item';
          }
          return null;
        },
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Select Item',
          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: 20.0),
      Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
              // Form is valid, handle submission
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                SnackBar(content: Text('Form submitted')),
              );
            }
          },
          child: Text('Submit'),
           ),
         ),
       ],
     ),
   );
  }
}


thnx. I specifically looking for DropDownMenu as it goes with Material 3.

I found the perfect solution for your question. Just wrap your DropDownWidget with FormField widget with a validator and builder parameter. You can validate it using normal formkey. Here is an example how you can achieve it.
FormField<String>(
  validator: (_) {
    if (widget.controller!.text.isEmpty) {
      return 'Required Field';
    }
    return null;
  },
  builder: (fieldState) {
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(widget.title),
        vSpace8,
        DropdownMenu(
          expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
          enableSearch: true,
          hintText: widget.hintText,
          requestFocusOnTap: true,
          onSelected: widget.onSelected,
          menuStyle: MenuStyle(
            backgroundColor: const WidgetStatePropertyAll(AppColors.black),
            shape: WidgetStatePropertyAll(
              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                side: BorderSide(color: AppColors.white.withOpacity(0.1)),
              ),
            ),
            padding: const WidgetStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.all(0)),
          ),
          menuHeight: h * 0.3,
          dropdownMenuEntries: widget.list
              .map(
                (e) => DropdownMenuEntry(
                  value: e,
                  label: e,
                  labelWidget: Text(e),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
        if (fieldState.hasError) ...[
          vSpace4,
          Text('Required field'),
        ]
      ],
    );
  },
);

